# Getting a JPopupMenu in a World Wind display

Tags: java, worldwind

I need to add a right-click `JPopupMenu` to a World Wind display. The World Wind display is in a `JPanel`. I pretty much just copied the member variables and methods of the `ApplicationTemplate.AppPanel` inner-class out of World Wind's example `ApplicationTemplate` class, pasted it into a GUI I need the WW-display in, and changed `this.add(component)` references from the copied code to `myJPanel.add(component)`.

It worked great other than the lack of the popup-menu; I have a World Wind display embedded into my application and am controlling it from my application's dialog's.

After adding a `JPopupMenu` to the world wind display's `JPanel`, it doesn't seem to show at all. I right-click, and nothing pops up. I don't think this is a heavyweight vs lightweight Java component issue hiding the menu, since I can attach the menu to a component above the World Wind display (WWD is in a `BorderLayout` CENTER, other component is at its NORTH) instead and the menu will happily enter the World Wind display's space without getting hidden by it. Just to be safe, I set the `JPopupMenu`'s `setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false)` and in a static initializer top of the main class I did `JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false)`

I did a test with a `MouseListener` attached to the `JPanel` that contains the World Wind display, and none of the `MouseListener` events are triggering. So my best guess is that I should not be adding the `JPopupMenu` to the `JPanel` but instead should be adding it to some specific sub-component of the wwd object. The wwd object itself does not appear to have a method for adding the popup menu, and I don't see anything like a "getGLCanvas" in the wwd's methods. If I am on the right track here, what component should the menu be added to, and how do I access that component?

So my question is pretty simple, or so it would seem: How do I get a `JPopupMenu` onto the World Wind display?

Secondarily, this question also begs the same of getting a `MouseListener` on the display, but I assume the answer to that will fall out of the answer to getting a `JPopupMenu` on the display.

Below is the World Wind template code which I inserted, along with my modifications to it. Another class elsewhere uses the `getComponent()` to add the `JPanel` containing the World Wind display to my application's user interface. I left in the default World Wind stuff that I commented out in case that is somehow significant. The loop through the String[] of layer names was just a way for me to easily show only the map and the unit scale. The `JPopupMenu` code is halfway down the constructor. Apologies for the messy code, but I thought you should see it as-is for best assistance.

```
class MyClass
{

protected JComponent component;
public JComponent getComponent() { return component; }

protected WorldWindow wwd;
protected StatusBar statusBar;
protected ToolTipController toolTipController;
protected HighlightController highlightController;

MyClass()
{
    boolean includeStatusBar = false;
    component = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    this.wwd = this.createWorldWindow();
    ((Component) this.wwd).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));//canvasSize);

    // Create the default model as described in the current worldwind properties.
    Model m = (Model) WorldWind.createConfigurationComponent(AVKey.MODEL_CLASS_NAME);
    this.wwd.setModel(m);

    // Setup a select listener for the worldmap click-and-go feature
//            this.wwd.addSelectListener(new ClickAndGoSelectListener(this.getWwd(), WorldMapLayer.class));

    component.add((Component) this.wwd, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    if (includeStatusBar)
    {
        this.statusBar = new StatusBar();
        component.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        this.statusBar.setEventSource(wwd);
    }

    // Add controllers to manage highlighting and tool tips.
//            this.toolTipController = new ToolTipController(this.getWwd(), AVKey.DISPLAY_NAME, null);
//            this.highlightController = new HighlightController(this.getWwd(), SelectEvent.ROLLOVER);

    java.util.List<String> desiredLayers = Arrays.asList(
        new String[] { "Blue Marble May 2004", /*"i-cubed Landsat",*/ "Scale bar"
        });
    for(Layer layer : getWwd().getModel().getLayers())
    {
        if(desiredLayers.contains( layer.getName() ))
        {
            System.out.println("INCLUDE " + layer.getName());
            layer.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("EXCLUDE " + layer.getName());
            layer.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }


    JMenu menuZoom = new JMenu("Zoom");
    JMenuItem menuZoom_1028 = new JMenuItem("1028");
    menuZoom.add(menuZoom_1028);
    JMenuItem menuZoom_512 = new JMenuItem("512");
    menuZoom.add(menuZoom_512);
    JMenuItem menuZoom_256 = new JMenuItem("256");
    menuZoom.add(menuZoom_256);
    JMenuItem menuZoom_128 = new JMenuItem("128");
    menuZoom.add(menuZoom_128);
    JMenuItem menuZoom_64 = new JMenuItem("64");
    menuZoom.add(menuZoom_64);
    JMenuItem menuZoom_32 = new JMenuItem("32");
    menuZoom.add(menuZoom_32);
    JPopupMenu rclickMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    rclickMenu.add(menuZoom);
    component.setComponentPopupMenu(rclickMenu);

    menuZoom.getPopupMenu().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);

    component.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("mouseClicked");
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("mousePressed");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("mouseReleased");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("mouseEntered");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("mouseExited");
        }
    });
}

protected WorldWindow createWorldWindow()
{
    return new WorldWindowGLCanvas();
}

public WorldWindow getWwd()
{
    return wwd;
}

public StatusBar getStatusBar()
{
    return statusBar;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I have finally figured out a workaround.

First I'll address my silly sub-question about getting the `GLPanel` from the World Wind wwd object: the wwd object *is* a `GLPanel`. Well, technically the `WorldWindow` is an interface, but in the case of the World Wind `ApplicationTemplate` application from which I am drawing, the implementation of the `WorldWindow` is a class which extends `GLPanel`. I did not notice that for a while.

As stated in question, mouse listeners applied to the `JPanel` which contains the World Wind display aren't triggered my mouse actions over the map, and the World Wind display has no methods for adding mouse listeners to itself. I finally realized that the World Window has a `getInputHandler()` which returns an object which you can add the mouse listener to. So I had to do `wwd.getInputHandler().addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);`

As I believed, the `JPopupMenu` was not being hidden by the World Wind display; it just wasn't being triggered to pop up. With the above fix for mouse listeners, I remedied this by opening the pop-up myself instead of relying on Swing's built-in right-click `JPopupMenu` support. I did this by calling `jPopupMenu.show(component, event.getX(), event.getY());` from within the mouse listener.

Here is the code I made to pop-up the menu (in the initialization code for the World Wind stuff):

```
    wwd.getInputHandler().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
        {
            // right-click context-menu
            if(event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
            {
                // component is my JPanel which contains the WorldWindow
                rclickMenu.show(component, event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
        }
    });
```

I also added a couple things that I needed which I'll mention in case it is useful. I added a check to make sure the point right-clicked was on the world map specifically, and I also wanted to know later what spot was right-clicked since some menu items are for interacting with whatever was right-clicked on.

After these additions, the code looked like this:

```
    wwd.getInputHandler().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
        {
            // right-click context-menu
            if(event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
            {
                Position p = wwd.getCurrentPosition();
                // abort if not on-map
                if(p == null) return;

                // need later to know what was right-clicked on
                mPositionAtRightClickMoment = wwd.getCurrentPosition();

                rclickMenu.show(component, event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
        }
    });
```